# eclipse "Run As --> Groovy Script" gives me the DEBUG info

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I right click the groovy class and select `Run As --> Groovy Script`. I can't find my `println` output in the console, but I get all these DEBUG messages. How can I get rid of them?

```
10:57:10.687 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "[\r][\n]"
10:57:10.687 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> GET /nexus/service/local/repositories/snapshots/content/devops/README.md/1.0.0-rc1/ HTTP/1.1
10:57:10.687 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Accept: application/xml, text/xml, application/xhtml+xml, application/atom+xml
10:57:10.687 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Host: localhost:8060
```

Comment: Could you post the script that you are trying to run?

Comment: @Gergely Toth, this is the script: https://gist.github.com/oliverdaff/2233777. I added it into my own Groovy project as one of the class.